# AngularJS - How to pass html attribute variable value to directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

...
...

**UPDATE**

**HTML**

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="item in items = ( data | filter: {isExists: true})">
    something
</my-directive>
<my-second-directive counter="{{items.length}}"></my-second-directive>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('directives')
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    ...
})
.directive('mySecondDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: false,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            counter: '@'
        },
        template: '',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            alert(scope.counter);
        }
    });
```

Excuse me I've not described my question well. My first directive should be ngRepeated, with filter. But in my second directive, I would like to allow to show a counter, how many first directive is currently instantiated, because the user will be able to add and remove instances. So I would like to get the value of the items.length by fly with the second directive. But the link() method of the second directive is fired prior the ngRepeat, so the value of the counter will be an empty string.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 2**

```
.directive('cardGroupHeader', function($templateCache){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        require: '^cardGroup',
        scope: {
            cbiscounter: '=?',
            cbcounter: '=?',
            cbisarrow: '@?'
        },
        template: $templateCache.get('card-group-header-tpl.html'),
        link: function(scope, $element, $attrs, cardGroupController) {
            scope.rowId = cardGroupController.getCurrentId();
            console.log(scope.cbcounter);

            scope.toggle = function () {
                cardGroupController.toggle(scope.rowId)
            }
            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                console.log(scope.cbcounter);
            });

            scope.$watch('scope.cbcounter', function (n, o) {
                if(n && n != o) {
                    console.log(n);
                }
            });
            //scope.cbcounter++;
        }
    };
})
```

HTML

```
<card-group-header cbiscounter="true" cbarrow="true" cbcounter="data.length">Waiting for Approval</card-group-header>
    <card-group-row cbCollapsed="false">
        <card ng-repeat="approveItem in data = (approveItems | filter: {isApproved: false, isRejected: false})">
```

TEMPLATE

```
$templateCache.put('card-group-header-tpl.html', '<div class="card-group-header" ng-click="toggle()"><span ng-transclude></span><span class="card-group-counter" ng-if="cbiscounter">{{cbcounter}}</span></div>');
```

When I change the `data.length` to `2`, this is transferred well. If I use the `data.length` the `scope.cbcounter` is always undefined. In case of `2` I've got it back on the `console.log(scope.cbcounter);`

Comment: Did you try to use two ways binding as shown in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `counter: '@'` means that you are accepting a string value. If you wanted to pass an expression you could either use:

```
 <my-second-directive counter="{{ items.length }}"></my-second-directive>
```

Or:

```
.directive('mySecondDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: false,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            counter: '=' // Accept two ways binding
        },
        template: '',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            alert(scope.counter); 
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**
I finally quite understand the problem! It's because of **attributes are not interpolated until after the link phase**. You have two following options:

The first option is wrapping every in the link inside `$timeout` to take it away from the event loop and be executed after DOM finished manipulating:

```
.directive('mySecondDirective', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: false,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            counter: '=' // Accept two ways binding
        },
        template: '',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                alert(scope.counter); 
            });
        }
    });
```

Secondly, using `$observe`:

```
attrs.$observe('counter', function(value){
 console.log(value);
});
```

or using `$watch` as @jusopi suggested.

Comment: While that is part of the problem, the other issue is that he wants to get the length of the items that are filtered, `{{item.length}}` gives the original array length.

Comment: I've tried it before, but because the second directive link() method is fired prior the ng-repeat somehow, the alert message will be empty.

Comment: @jusopi you are not right. the filtered are the items in that case, and the data is the original.

Comment: @MontyX I don't quite understand the problem. If the `items` is your original data, this means that it's bound to your scope object in your controller. So, how does it relate to the first directive? The two directives should be independent from each other.

Comment: @LVarayut you are answered my original question well, but I've made a mistake in the description. Let me modify my question.

Comment: @MontyX you might try setting `priority` on the second directive to a lower number (e.g. -100) so that it gets processed later.  I admit i don't quite understand the full implications of the priority value when the directives are not getting processed on the same DOM node.

Comment: @jusopi let me check the `priority` .... this was not worked. I think the link() is running before the DOM is rendered, and the ngRepeat is running only during the rendering.

Comment: @MontyX are you actually needing to use the alert? You can see in this example http://plnkr.co/edit/xt95gb3cTXfUEHgpWK1W?p=preview that the directive gets the right value to the isolate scope.

Comment: @jusopi this is still not working in my code somehow. Is there any difference between JS and CS in this case?

Comment: @MontyX I don't think so. Actually, it should work if you use two ways binding as I suggested at the first time. If it's not, there should be some problem in your code. You should put your code in the Plunkr. So, we can help you easier.

Comment: @jusopi the $timeout is not a good solution in case of link() methods, because the rendering is waiting for the timeout. I'm just checking the $observe, currently without a good result :(

Comment: @jusopi I've checked the `$observe` and `$watch` too as you can see it in my code. When I try to use the `data.length` binding, the attribute will be always `undefined` and the `$observe` and `$watch` won't be fired anytime. The `cbcounter` will be always `undefined` not just during the `link()` phase.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be what you want.

## Html

```
<div ng-app="testapp" ng-controller="testctrl">

    <div ng-repeat="item in filtereditems">
        {{item}}
    </div>
    <testdir counter="filtereditems.length" />

</div>
```

## Javascript

```
angular.module('testapp', [])
.directive('testdir', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            counter: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            alert(scope.counter);
        }
    }
})
.controller('testctrl', function($scope, $filter){
    $scope.items = [
        {name: 'A', isExists: true},
        {name: 'B', isExists: false},
        {name: 'C', isExists: true},
        {name: 'D', isExists: false}
    ];
    $scope.filtereditems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, {isExists: true});
})
```

[My jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/zp82e3xm/12/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @LVarayut's answer about the scope's binding expression, the reason the alert is `undefined` is because linking is not part of the *$digest* cycle.  So binding and data hasn't be effected yet (don't quote me on that, it's the best way I could verbalize what I'm showing in the code below).

Instead you need to use a watcher to trigger the alert

```
link: ($scope, elem, attrs)-> 

  #undefined because linking isn't part of the $digest cycle
  #alert $scope.count 

  $scope.$watch 'count', (n, o)->
    if n and n isnt o 
      true
      #alert n
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xt95gb3cTXfUEHgpWK1W?p=preview

Comment: I think that `link` is part of the digest cycle. The reason behind should be something else.

Comment: This was what I was trying to say - *Post link is the last function to execute. Now the transclusion is complete, the template is linked to a scope, and the view will update with data bound values after the next digest cycle .* - http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx

Comment: I bet the `ng-repeat` is the culprit and this is an *edge case* whereby the filtered data set is created after the DOM renders.  Ergo the $watch.  He could probably do this via `$timeout` as well, albeit wouldn't update as the filtered data changes.